# How to I correct this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get this mysql query to work, but it will not.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gospel_library`.`catalog_book_files` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `book_order` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `added` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `version` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `downloads` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `file` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `uri` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `catalog_book_files_ndx1` (`book_id` ASC, `book_order` ASC),
  INDEX `catalog_book_files.fk1_idx` (),
  CONSTRAINT `catalog_book_files.fk1`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `gospel_library`.`catalog_book` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '), CONSTRAINT `catalog_book_files.fk1` FOREIGN KEY () REFERENCES
>   `gosp' at line 13

I am trying to figure out what solution I would use to correct this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must specify foreign and candidate keys.

Comment: You might want to make the title a little more informative :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are creating an index with no columns specified.  Either Remove

```
INDEX `catalog_book_files.fk1_idx` (),
```

or change it to specify one or more columns

```
INDEX `catalog_book_files.fk1_idx` (`somecolumn`),
```

Comment: My issue with not linking it to a column, is this is a DB that someone has created and is using, they sent it to me to help manipulate some of the data.

Comment: Your issue *is* with linking it to a column. The index as it is now is invalid. If someone sent this to you, then they sent you an invalid script.

Comment: They sent me a MySQL Workbench model. Not a sql file.